# A bit convoluted puzzle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My beginning is the end of the start of the close
>
> My midpoint is the end of the start of the beginning
>
> My end is the start of the close of the midpoint

What accessible word am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a

> login

*My beginning is the end of the start of the close*

> The letters **Lo** are at the end of the start of the word c**lo**se.

*My midpoint is the end of the start of the beginning*

> The letter **g** is at the end of the start of the word be**g**inning.

*My end is the start of the close of the midpoint*

> The letters **in** are at the start of the "close" (end) in midpo**in**t.

*What accessible word am I?*

> This might refer to everyone's login (username) being publicly visible by everyone, or simply that anyone can log themselves on SE!
>  (Clarification from OP) Logins allow access to more functions on most sites.

Comment: That was fast. May be comment on Accessible?

Comment: Edited! Although I'm not sure of my answer for it...

Comment: Allows you access